# Azure re-place spending limit

Tags: sql, web-services, azure, limit, subscription

In Azure, I exceeded what was in my subscription by making my SQL Database 'Business' edition instead of 'Web'. The spending limit disabled my account, but I wanted my services back up and running. Because my account was disabled I couldn't do anything in the management portal. So I removed the spending limit, and changed the SQL type back to 'Web' from 'Business'.

Now I want the spending limit back, but I don't know how to place it. Does it get placed automatically next month? Can I set it myself?

Please reply quickly, this is urgent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time it is not possible to reset the spending cap.  The [information about spending caps](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/spending-limits/) is pretty straight forward on this.

> *"You can remove the Spending Limit at any time. However, once removed, the Spending Limit feature cannot be re-enabled. You should remove this Spending Limit on any subscription that has applications that you cannot afford to go offline."*

Comment: Ok thanks. I contacted Azure to see if there was anything they could do, but they said they couldn't do anything